# How to find the number of variables in common between variables two by two in a column R compared to variables in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, count, data-cleaning

I'm working on R, I have a character data table like that :

```
Species<- c("lion", "tiger", "lion","tiger","donkey","lion","donkey")
Countries <- c("Tanzania", "Tanzania", "Kenya","Kenya","Italia","Niger","France")

df <- data.frame(Species, Countries)
```

| Species | Countries |
| --- | --- |
| lion | Tanzania |
| tiger | Tanzania |
| lion | Kenya |
| tiger | Kenya |
| donkey | Italia |
| lion | Niger |
| donkey | France |

With this table, I would like to have for each country of my dataframe the number of species in common for the countries 2 by 2, and have a final table like this one:

| Countries1 | Countries2 | number_common_species |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kenya | Tanzania | 2 |
| Italia | Tanzania | 0 |
| Italia | Kenya | 0 |
| Niger | Kenya | 1 |
| Niger | Tanzania | 1 |
| Italia | Niger | 0 |
| Italia | France | 1 |
| Tanzania | France | 0 |
| Kenya | France | 0 |
| Niger | France | 0 |

I have a really big dataset with a lot of species.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Do you want `subset(as.data.frame.table(crossprod(table(df))), Countries != Countries.1)`

Comment: The problem with that approach @akrun is that it includes two copies of each pair e.g it has France - Italia and Italia - France

Comment: @AllanCameron yes, I was thinking about `subset(as.data.frame.table(crossprod(table(df)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), Countries != Countries.1&(!duplicated(pmin(Countries, Countries.1), pmax(Countries, Countries.1))))`

Comment: Yes, that looks good @akrun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make a data frame of each pairwise combination of countries, then find the length of the set of species that each pair has in common:

```
counts <- data.frame(t(combn(unique(dat$Countries),2)))
counts$count <- apply(counts, 1, function(x) length(intersect( dat$Species[dat$Countries==x[1]], 
                                                               dat$Species[dat$Countries==x[2]])))
counts

         X1     X2 count
1  Tanzania  Kenya     2
2  Tanzania Italia     0
3  Tanzania  Niger     1
4  Tanzania France     0
5     Kenya Italia     0
6     Kenya  Niger     1
7     Kenya France     0
8    Italia  Niger     0
9    Italia France     1
10    Niger France     0
```

Answer (score 4):

This is harder than it looks, and hopefully someone has a more elegant solution:

```r
df2 <- expand.grid(country2 = sort(unique(df$Countries)),
                   country1 = sort(unique(df$Countries)))[2:1]
cp <- crossprod(table(df$Species, df$Countries))
df2$common <- c(cp)
df2 <- df2[c(lower.tri(cp)),]

df2
#>    country1 country2 common
#> 2    France   Italia      1
#> 3    France    Kenya      0
#> 4    France    Niger      0
#> 5    France Tanzania      0
#> 8    Italia    Kenya      0
#> 9    Italia    Niger      0
#> 10   Italia Tanzania      0
#> 14    Kenya    Niger      1
#> 15    Kenya Tanzania      2
#> 20    Niger Tanzania      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Another base R option using `crossprod` + `as.table` + `as.data.frame`

```
m <- crossprod(table(df))
m[upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
na.omit(as.data.frame(as.table(m)))
```

gives

```
   Countries Countries.1 Freq
2     Italia      France    1
3      Kenya      France    0
4      Niger      France    0
5   Tanzania      France    0
8      Kenya      Italia    0
9      Niger      Italia    0
10  Tanzania      Italia    0
14     Niger       Kenya    1
15  Tanzania       Kenya    2
20  Tanzania       Niger    1
```

Comment: Very nice Thomas. I was fascinated to see that the lower triangle of an m x m matrix  picks out the correct indices of an expand.grid data frame when we need unique pairs, but your way is more direct and doesn't require this trick.

Comment: I think you can use the best of both your answers and simplify it slightly more - `cp <- crossprod(table(df)); as.data.frame.table(cp)[lower.tri(cp),]`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks. Your use of `lower.tri` for dataframe subsetting is also cool, which is the first time I see how it is used. :)

Comment: @thelatemail A nice proposal with such kind of combo, thanks!